# How to fix "undefined is not object" in this case "movieItem.poster_path" using ListItem native-base inside Flatlist react-native?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

I'm calling data from this API https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=9a4a662a126525b07d4b84b079d809d8&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.asc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1

and fetching the url, so I can get which data to display in mobile device, the problem is the in native-base library, List Component is deprecated so, the documentation say should use Flatlist Component from official react-native, and here the code :

```
// render data list
    renderDataMovieList = ({ movieItem }) => {
        return(
            <ListItem Thumbnail>
                <Left>
                    <Thumbnail square large source= {{ uri:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movieItem.poster_path }}/>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>{ movieItem.title }</Text>
                                <Text note >Release Date : { movieItem.release_date }</Text>
                                <Text note >Vote Avarage : { movieItem.vote_average }</Text>
                                <Text note >Language : { movieItem.original_language}</Text>
                        </Body>
                </Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name="arrow-forward" style={{ color: "#999" }}/>
                    </Button>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name="menu" />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Title>Movie List</Title>
                        </Body>
                    <Right />
                </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <FlatList 
                            data = { this.state.data }
                            renderItem = { this.renderDataMovieList}
                            keyExtractor={ movieItem => movieItem.id }
                            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                            initialNumToRender={5}
                        />
                    </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

But after I ran that code, I get this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'movieItem.poster_path')

I was following this code pattern : http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html

but I still get the error.

Comment: What is `movieItem`?

Comment: is variable for fetching and call the data from the API

Comment: But what is its value?

Comment: value from API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming movieItem is undefined(that is why the error).

Ideally, you should wait till movies call is completed and then call the component and also you are not passing movieItem data to renderDataMovieList method.

Assuming movieItem is the data you are waiting for.

```
   { movieItem &&
        <FlatList 
            data = { this.state.data }
            renderItem = { this.renderDataMovieList({ movieItem: movieItem }) }
            keyExtractor={ movieItem => movieItem.id }
            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            initialNumToRender={5}
        />
   }
```

Comment: after learn your code answer, I found this code pattern for my problem , look like this renderItem = { movieItem => this.renderDataMovieList({ movieItem: movieItem })} , but the movie poster is gone, and I found the warning in android emulator warning : invalid child context

Comment: You just send movieItem as a simple parameter to renderDataMovieList.
`this.renderDataMovieList(movieItem)` and while receiving `renderDataMovieList = (movieItem) => {`

Comment: To solve issue of invalid child context use `keyExtractor={ movieItem => movieItem.id.toString() }`

Comment: before I'm argue from your question, I;m just wanna say, thank you very much for solving for keyExtractor problem, yeah that make sense to me. for movieItem , the emulator doesn't show the data from API just properties. any suggest ?

Comment: ty for the answer that give me a clue for better solving